# Why is the script reading all values despite using "WHERE"?

Tags: php, database

I am creating a table that echo out replied messages and not replied messages.

My script for not replied messages worked well,only those not replied appeared.
But my other script for replied messages echo all data, both replied and not replied.

my script in one page,

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                require_once 'dbfunction.php';
                $con = getDbConnect();
                

                if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                    $sqlQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM feedback  WHERE status = 0";

                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // fetch the record
                        $feedback[$row['record']] = $row;
                    }

                    mysqli_close($con);
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                ?>

                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Customer Feedback - await for reply</h2>     
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Relpy</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($feedback as $id => $info) {
                            echo '<tbody>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['message'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td><button class="btn btn-info">' . 'Reply' . '</button></td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '</tbody>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                require_once 'dbfunction.php';
                $con = getDbConnect();
                

                if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                    $sqlQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM feedback  WHERE status != 0";

                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // fetch the record
                        $feedback[$row['record']] = $row;
                    }

                    mysqli_close($con);
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                ?>

                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Customer Feedback - Replied</h2>     
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Relpy</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($feedback as $id => $info) {
                            echo '<tbody>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info['message'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . 'Replied' . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '</tbody>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

How can i change it?

Comment: I think @Dagon is asking what is the data type for feedback.status

Comment: if this really on the same page, why include the db functions twice and just make one select order by status and echo in 2 blocks

Comment: status is either 0 or 1. Zero 0 = not replied. One 1= replied.

Comment: Doesn't look like mysqli_fetch_array($result) gets re-initialized.  So is it possible it contains the results from the first run though, and the second is just appended?... nevermind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by changing some of the codes in the second table

```html
<?php
                require_once 'dbfunction.php';
                $con = getDbConnect();
                

                if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                    $sqlQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM feedback  WHERE status != 0";

                    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { // fetch the record
                        $feedback2[$row2['record']] = $row2;
                    }

                    mysqli_close($con);
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                ?>

                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Customer Feedback - Replied</h2>     
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Relpy</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($feedback2 as $id2 => $info2) {
                            echo '<tbody>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info2['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info2['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $info2['message'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . 'Replied' . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '</tbody>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
```